# how to add device to distribution provisioning profile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile

My distribution provisioning profile suddenly has no devices.
I want to add my iphone to the distribution profile, but I can't find where I dan do this.

I can create a new profile, but I want to use the existing one.

Anyone know where I can add my device to the existing distribution profile?

UPDATE: the distribution profile is generated by Xcode (has XC: prefix), but it seems that I can't add devices to this kind of profile in the member center. How can I do this from Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW10).

Alternatively, you can connect your device to your Mac, and add the device via Xcode. This works for development profiles, but I'm not sure if this works for distribution profiles, though.

Comment: I can register my device in Member Center, but I can't add it to an existing distribution profile...

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between an AppStore distribution profile and an adhoc distribution profile. With adhoc, it is possible to assign devices. With the AppStore, it is for all devices, but from the App Store (so not using the cable attached to your device).